# Why can not reach my web application?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am trying to create a simple web application with using Maven which is just connects to mssql server and my IDE is IntelliJ. Here is my index.jsp file:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.IOException" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection connection = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlServer://127.0.0.1;         
databaseName=database password=passwordd");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from tablo 
where id = 10");
        while(resultSet.next()){
            out.println(resultSet.getArray(0) + " " + resultSet.getArray(1));
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

I did not change the web.xml file so it is just empty. My problem is that when I run the web application on tomcat server, I got HTTP Status 404 - Not Found error. The URL is `"http://localhost:8080/"`. And I also tried `http://localhost:8080/index.jsp` and `"http://localhost:8080/webapp/index.jsp"` but result is same. Feel like I did not gave enough information, it is just because I am new at creating web applications. Where am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I just change the way that I deploy my web project and worked. It was `mywebapp: war` and now `mywebapp: war exploded`. Why it worked now? What is the difference between them or pointing my project folder? –

Comment: I just change the way that I deploy my web project and worked. It was mywebapp: war and and now mywebapp: war exploded. Why it worked now? What is the difference between them or pointing my project folder?

Comment: you should delete or update this question, if you have any other question

Comment: You could also answer your own question first putting the other configuration you had in an update to your question and then answer your question with the configuration which was correct.  That way if other people have the same problem - you will have helped them.  Sorry, not sure why it wasn't accessible when not exploded

Comment: I updated my question, thanks.

Comment: Looking around at other SO posts, it looks like it might be the way your ?artifacts? are configured, e.g if intelli-j is starting tomcat for you - when it's doing the war exploded it ends up in the correct directory but when its just a war, its not being deployed to the correct place?

Comment: Also remember, at least with Eclipse, the server configuration could be set to either deploy to a temporary location or the jboss installation folder - ditto with tomcat.  If intelli-j is starting tomcat, and its got a temp or different catalina_home, if you manually copied the war to the tomcat install - its not the actual tomcat instance thats running.

Comment: @JGlass I got this, thanks a lot. I will delete the question soon.

Comment: I wouldnt necessarily delete it if you figured out what the problem was in the IDE and can put it in as an answer - I would but I dont know what helped you ;-)  but if others have the same issue and you saw a setting that you had wrong, you'll help them with your answer

Comment: @JGlass I will do that, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was about the way I deployed my web project. When I deploy it as `MyWebApp: war exploded` it worked perfectly. Hope it will help someone.